# cloth simulation problem

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make a simple cloth simulation in the skirt of my mesh

I want something like this but with cloth colission of course

[image]

but this happens when I turn on cloth colission.

[image]

it looks like the problem is in cloth colission config. but I dont know exactly where.

Somebody knows what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't looked in detail at your cloth configuration, I notice that your model is less than 1 cubic unit in size.  I have found (much to my chagrin) that trying to run cloth physics on anything that small has the unfortunate result that the cloth jiggles around and eventually gets sucked up into whatever model it is supposed to be colliding with.

Try scaling the model(s) up by 100x and apply. Then set the scene units to centimeters (If you want units to display realistically).

[image: Scene setting centimeters]

Comment: I tried to make my mesh bigger but it does not grow proportionally